# what is the cause of runtime error in the following code

Tags: c, string, char, strcmp

I was trying to solve a problem( https://www.codechef.com/problems/COOK82A) on an online judge. Following is the code for the problem.When i submit the judge gives runtime error.Can anybody help me

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) 

{

    int a,i,j,flag,pos,flag1,pos1;
    char team[15];
    int score[4];
    scanf("%d",&a);
    while(a--)
    {

        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            scanf("%s",&team[i]);
            scanf("%d",&score[i]);
        }
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {

            if(team[i]=="Barcelona")
            pos=i;
            if(team[i]=="Eibar")
            flag=i;
            if(team[i]=="RealMadrid")
            pos1=i;
            if(team[i]=="Malaga")
            flag1=i;

        }
            if((score[pos]>score[flag]) && (score[flag1]>score[pos1]))
            printf("Barcelona\n");
            else
            printf("RealMadrid\n");
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Please refrain asking questions about online code judge engines here. It's very  unlikely that anyone could tell you where you failed from their test cases, as these aren't disclosed usually. Even if what you tested was running at your local environment, you may have missed to test some edge cases which are applied in the online challenge. Be creative and try to find them. Additionally there's probably no value for such questions in the long term, other than cheating the online contest, and nothing is learned.

Comment: `team[i]` is a `char`. `"Barcelona"` is a `char*`.

Comment: You seem to have lots of misudnerstandings about the difference between strings and chars.

Comment: The cause is a failure to debug.

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
  scanf("%s",&team[i]);
```

is wrong, you don't have space to store a *string*. You can store a `char` in the memory pointed by `&team[i]`, but not a null-terminated `char` array.

To put it in other way, your `team` is an array of `char`s, whereas, you seem to be in need of array of `char` arrays, something like

```
#define NAMESIZ 32
#define TEAMSIZ 15

char team[TEAMSIZ][TEAMSIZ] = {0};
```

and then, properly using `team[i]` (boils to an address itself) can help.

---

After this error, there's one more logical error which must be fixed. You are using `==` operator to compare *strings* which is not possible. You need to use `strcmp()` to compare strings (i.e., contents of null-terminated `char` arrays).

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
scanf("%s",&team[i]); is wrong.
```

you declared a team[15] as a character array, but are storing the no. of strings  in it.
if you want to do so,

```
scanf("%s",&team[i])
```

then declare a two dimensional character array like.

```
char arrayOfWords[NUMBER_OF_WORDS][MAX_SIZE_OF_WORD];
```

then you need to enter the string this way:
int i;

```
for (i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_WORDS; i++) {
    scanf ("%s" , arrayOfWords[i]);
}
```

and to print or process this array, you need to do:

```
for (i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_WORDS; i++) {
    printf ("%s" , arrayOfWords[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i will implement it